# Use "log4j1 to log4j2 bridge" when have access to classes like "appenders" or "WriteLogger" from log4j1

Tags: java, maven, log4j

My new project is dependent to old project that use log4j1.
In old project have a lot of (5000 -/+) access to the jar.

In the documentation of "log4j bridge" write the one of requires is to not access to some of class and methods.
The old project use them

Here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/migration.html - article 1.

What can I do?